# Draggable with Vue.js, not being able to return to original position

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, vue.js

I'm attempting to have an element's draggable functionality depend on a click event. I'm using jquery-ui's draggable method (within a vue.js instance).

In my Vue instance I have these two data properties: *isVisible* and a *isDraggable*. They assume a truthy or falsy value each time the user clicks a button. On my methods object I have the following:

```
methods: {
    toggleBox: function() {
        this.IsVisible = !this.IsVisible;
        this.isDraggable = !this.isDraggable;
    }
}
```

I'm using the *destroy* method *in order to have the targeted element return to its original position* (documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy)). However, I am not getting the intended result, as can be seen in the jsfiddle below. The following is one of many (unsuccessful) attemtps to tackle this issue:

```
ready: function() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
        if (this.isDraggable == true) {
            $('.box').draggable({
                containment: "window"
            })
        } else if (this.isDraggable == false) {
            $('.box').draggable(
                "destroy"
            )
        }
    })
}
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/7zp5er3f/17/). I wonder what I'm doing wrong here? Any hint appreciated.

Comment: Tried jqueryui's _revert_ method, at no avail either. Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/7zp5er3f/29/)

Comment: I put a `console.log` within the `nextTick` function and it's only fired once, on the initial load. What about adding some logic to `toggleBox` to reset the position of the element using jquery's `offset` method? So when the visibility is set to false, you reset the position e.g. `$('.selector').offset({ top: 0, left: 0});`?, where the values for `top` and `left` are defined by you.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I tried that but I'm having the same issue as before. That is, no matter the method employed, the value of _isVisible_ is not having a direct effect on the box's position. Perhaps vm.$watch could be of use here.

Comment: Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/7zp5er3f/32/) help?

Comment: That's it! It seems so straightforward now... Thank you so much! Why putting the conditional in the ready hook did not work by itself alone, but putting it inside the toggleBox method as well worked just fine, is beyond me, which only goes to show how noob I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ready` function only gets called once, during initialization of the `vm` element. Whenever you click on the "toggle" button, there's nothing that tells the `nextTick` method to execute. I'm not at all familiar with the vue api, so there probably will be a way to do what you want using the `nextTick` method.

Given my lack of knowledge regarding the api, I came up with a solution that seemed the most straightforward for your requirements i.e. updating the `toggleBox` method to check the `isDraggable` property and resetting the position of the box according to its value.

If you introduce other elements, you'd need to implement a solution that takes into account all of the default positions and re-apply them when you click the "toggle" button.

```
toggleBox: function() {
  this.IsVisible = !this.IsVisible;
  this.isDraggable = !this.isDraggable;
  if (this.isDraggable) {
    $('.box').draggable({
      containment: "window"
    })
  } else if (!this.isDraggable) {
    $('.box').offset({ top: 8, left: 8});
  }
}
```

**[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/7zp5er3f/34/)**

Comment: Thank you once again for the solution, as well as for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Yass's answer above, if instead of hard-coding the `offset`'s top position of the element `.box` , you wanted to calculate it, here's one way to do it (which is useful in those cases where the browser's window changes size for instance):

```
toggleBox: function() {

    this.IsVisible = !this.IsVisible;
    this.isDraggable = !this.isDraggable;


    var body = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    var element = document.querySelector('.box').getBoundingClientRect();

    var topPos = body.height - element.height;

    if (this.isDraggable) {
       $('.box').draggable({
          containment: "window"
       })
    }
    else if (!this.isDraggable) {
       $('.box').offset({ 
           top: this.topPos, 
           left: 8});
    }
}
```